# AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute 'open' in python 2.4

Tags: python, attributeerror

```
storefile(ftpcon, file, archive.open('NONVOL/'+file))
```

gives me AttributeError: ZipFile instance has no attribute `open`

but when I change `.open` to `.read` (since open() is was not available in 2.4) I get:

AttributeError: `str` object has no attribute `read`

in:

```
ftpcon.storbinary('STOR ' + filename.strip(), file)
```